# Array not accessible from method

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I have code:

```
class Blah
  @hello = ["a", "b", "c"]
  puts @hello[0]

  def something()
    puts "abc"
    #puts @hello[0]
  end
end

z = Blah.new()
z.something()

puts @hello[0]
```

It results in the output:

```
a
abc
```

If I uncomment

```
#puts @hello[0]
```

and try to output the first result of the array `@hello`, which is `a`, I get this error:

```
array_2.rb:13:in `something': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Why can I not get the result:

```
a
abc
a
```

Why doesn't my code work? An array such as `@example` should be accessible not just in the the class, but also in the `something` method. Why can't I access `@hello[0]` within methods? Why is `@hello[0]` only accessible within the class, and not the method? Need someone to fix my code so that I can access `@array` within the method.

Comment: The first `@hello` is a *class* instance variable, not an *instance* variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize instance variable in instance methods, but you are doing this in the scope of the class body, which isn't going to work.

If you set `@hello` from the `initialize` method, it should work like you expect.

```
class Blah
  def initialize
    @hello = ["a","b","c"]
  end

  def something()
    puts @hello[0]
  end
end

Blah.new.something #=> 'a'
```

It works this way so that you can pass arguments when instantiating a class, and each instance may have different data stored in its instance variables.